# Hardware Store - Logic grid, zebra puzzle style

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

You can play it online here: https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/hardware-store/

```
|            | Man #1 | Man #2 | Man #3 | Man #4 | Man #5 |
|------------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| shirt      |        |        |        |        |        |
| name       |        |        |        |        |        |
| tool       |        |        |        |        |        |
| discount   |        |        |        |        |        |
| profession |        |        |        |        |        |
| age        |        |        |        |        |        |
```

Five men (leftmost is #1) are next to each other at a hardware store. Each one is buying a specific tool and getting an discount. Solve this logic problem to discover these informations.

- shirt: blue, green, red, white, yellow
- name: Billy, Dennis, George, Larry, Philip
- tool: drill, hammer, saw, screwdriver, wrench
- discount: 5%, 10%, 15%, 20%, 25%
- profession: electrician, engineer, mechanic, plumber, technician
- age: 35, 40, 45, 50, 55

Clues:

1. The man wearning the Yellow shirt is somewhere to the left of the Mechanic.
2. Billy is buying a tool with 20% off.
3. The guy buying a tool with 15% discount is at one of the ends.
4. The 45 years old man is somewhere between the Plumber and the 35 years old man, in that order.
5. The one buying a tool with the biggest discount is next to the 50 years old man.
6. Dennis is wearning the Green shirt.
7. The 50 years old man is in the middle.
8. Larry is next to the man that is buying a tool with the smallest discount.
9. The one buying a Hammer is somewhere between the man buying the Wrench and the man buying the Screwdriver, in that order.
10. The Technician is at the third position.
11. The Plumber is next to the man wearning the Green shirt.
12. The oldest man is buying a Drill.
13. The guy wearning the White shirt is somewhere to the right of the man wearning the Blue shirt.
14. The man buying a Hammer is somewhere between the one who is getting 15% discount and the one buying a Saw, in that order.
15. George is next to the Electrician.
16. The men buying tools with 5% and 25% off are next to each other.
17. Philip is buying a Saw.
18. At the second position is the man buying a Drill.
19. The man wearning the Yellow shirt is next to the one buying a Saw.
20. The guy getting the best discount is somewhere between the 55 years old man and the man buying a tool with 10% off, in that order.
21. The man wearning the Red shirt is next to the man buying a tool with 15% discount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll post the picture from doing it on that site, I can't get the text version to work with spoilers stuff though.

> [image]

Here's the text version:

> ```
> |            | Man  #1 | Man  #2 |  Man  #3  |   Man #4   | Man  #5 |
> |------------|---------|---------|-----------|------------|---------|
> | Shirt      |Green    |Red      |Blue       |Yellow      |White    |
> | Name       |Dennis   |Billy    |George     |Larry       |Philip   |
> | Tool       |Wrench   |Drill    |Hammer     |Screwdriver |Saw      |
> | Discount   |15%      |20%      |5%         |25%         |10%      |
> | Profession |Engineer |Plumber  |Technician |Electrician |Mechanic |
> | Age        |40 years |55 years |50 years   |45 years    |35 years |
> ```

Comment: Added a text version for you.

Comment: Ohh so that's how you get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Preformating tags are useful :P